# Create React App: Setting OG image with PUBIC_URL does not work

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to set `og-image` to CRA app and I am doing like this:

`<meta content="website" property="og:type" />
<meta content="%PUBLIC_URL%/og-image.png" property="og:image" />
<meta content="Tile goes here..." property="og:title" />`

An image is inside `pubic` folder, but the image does not show on op.
When I do `http://localhost:3000/og-images.png`, it works. However, I do not want to set fixed value here.

What I am doing wrong?

Edit: my folder structure:

```
app
  - public
    - index.html
    - favicon.ico
    - og-image.png
  - src
```

Comment: can you please share your folder structure?

Comment: @rajibkarmaker I added it

Comment: No that is not possible. there's no way to solve this without server-side rendering You can add server-side rendering just for meta tags, and leave the rest of the app being rendered only on the client. Please do some research by yourself. I'm not sure but it may help you.  

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta   

https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet

https://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/

Comment: @rajibkarmaker thank you for you response.I have an another question regarding a similar stuff. 
I have favicon inside public folder, and unlike og image, it works. 
Do you know why?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am struggling with the exact same issue. I don't understand how this is not more widely discussed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by **having a sever.js serving the bundle and static files** which will allow you to add dynamic meta tags to your ReactJS App.

You can find a detail explanation on how to do that here in this post:

https://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/

Hope this still helps anyone out there